# Calico prints "Hit error connecting to datastore: connection refused"

Tags: networking, kubernetes, calico

I created a cluster on an Ubuntu server using this command:

```
> kubeadm init --cri-socket /var/run/dockershim.sock --control-plane-endpoint servername.local --apiserver-cert-extra-sans servername.local
```

I added Calico like this:

```
> curl https://docs.projectcalico.org/manifests/calico.yaml -o calico.yaml
> kubectl apply -f calico.yaml
```

The Calico pod prints errors:

```
> kubectl --namespace kube-system logs calico-node-2cg7x
2021-01-05 16:34:46.846 [INFO][8] startup/startup.go 379: Early log level set to info
2021-01-05 16:34:46.846 [INFO][8] startup/startup.go 395: Using NODENAME environment for node name
2021-01-05 16:34:46.846 [INFO][8] startup/startup.go 407: Determined node name: servername
2021-01-05 16:34:46.847 [INFO][8] startup/startup.go 439: Checking datastore connection
2021-01-05 16:34:46.853 [INFO][8] startup/startup.go 454: Hit error connecting to datastore - retry error=Get "https://10.96.0.1:443/api/v1/nodes/foo": dial tcp 10.96.0.1:443: connect: connection refused
2021-01-05 16:34:47.859 [INFO][8] startup/startup.go 454: Hit error connecting to datastore - retry error=Get "https://10.96.0.1:443/api/v1/nodes/foo": dial tcp 10.96.0.1:443: connect: connection refused
2021-01-05 16:34:48.866 [INFO][8] startup/startup.go 454: Hit error connecting to datastore - retry error=Get "https://10.96.0.1:443/api/v1/nodes/foo": dial tcp 10.96.0.1:443: connect: connection refused
2021-01-05 16:34:49.872 [INFO][8] startup/startup.go 454: Hit error connecting to datastore - retry error=Get "https://10.96.0.1:443/api/v1/nodes/foo": dial tcp 10.96.0.1:443: connect: connection refused
2021-01-05 16:34:50.878 [INFO][8] startup/startup.go 454: Hit error connecting to datastore - retry error=Get "https://10.96.0.1:443/api/v1/nodes/foo": dial tcp 10.96.0.1:443: connect: connection refused
2021-01-05 16:34:51.884 [INFO][8] startup/startup.go 454: Hit error connecting to datastore - retry error=Get "https://10.96.0.1:443/api/v1/nodes/foo": dial tcp 10.96.0.1:443: connect: connection refused
2021-01-05 16:34:52.890 [INFO][8] startup/startup.go 454: Hit error connecting to datastore - retry error=Get "https://10.96.0.1:443/api/v1/nodes/foo": dial tcp 10.96.0.1:443: connect: connection refused
2021-01-05 16:34:53.896 [INFO][8] startup/startup.go 454: Hit error connecting to datastore - retry error=Get "https://10.96.0.1:443/api/v1/nodes/foo": dial tcp 10.96.0.1:443: connect: connection refused
```

I don't know what `10.96.0.1` is. It doesn't have any ports open:

```
> ping 10.96.0.1 -c 1
PING 10.96.0.1 (10.96.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.96.0.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=248 time=5.62 ms

--- 10.96.0.1 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 5.621/5.621/5.621/0.000 ms

> nmap 10.96.0.1

Starting Nmap 7.60 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2021-01-05 17:37 CET
Nmap scan report for 10.96.0.1
Host is up (0.018s latency).
All 1000 scanned ports on 10.96.0.1 are closed

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 1.62 seconds
```

The pod actually has IP `192.168.1.19`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: 10.96.0.1 is the IP of kube-apiserver's service. Can you check if apiserver is up and running? Is there any firewall/proxy that might block the connection?

Comment: I am having exact same issue. I am using aws ec2 and used public dns for control-plane-endpoint.

Comment: It's hard to say what could be the issue here without more details. Could you pleas provide the info that @MariuszK requested: Can you check if apiserver is up and running? Is there any firewall/proxy that might block the connection?

Comment: Apiserver is up & running and it is able to launch calico-node pod on the host but calico-node is not able to each to apiserver. My node is behind a gateway that has a public address. My master node is set up with control plane endpoint as dns address.

Comment: @NishankSingla It will be hard and confusing to answer your question under someone else's one. Please describe your problem in a separate thread so the community could help you. We should not mix things up here.

Comment: @acl Could you please address my previous question? Also, are you able to exec into the Calico Pod and reach the api-server from it?

Comment: @Wytrzymały Wiktor Thanks for trying to help, but I ended up giving up, and got it to work on a new machine after a clean install of Ubuntu. I guess some service was conflicting with Kubernetes.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, in my case adding `--apiserver-advertise-address=<server-address>` parameter was the solution.

Comment: Is there a way this could be passed as a value to the Calico chart?

Answer (score 0):

The cause is: the iptables rule of kubernetes blocks the connection, shown as follow:

```
Chain KUBE-SERVICES (2 references)
pkts    bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
1773   106380 REJECT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            10.96.0.1            /* default/kubernetes:https has no endpoints */ tcp dpt:443 reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
```

Comment: So What should be done in this case? is deleting this route the right solution?